# How to reset the ID of customers in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my magento admin panel there have Customer ID as `9756`.

I need to reset it start with `1`.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this (easily) unless you want to remove all customers by truncating the table `customer_entity`.
Actually you can do this without losing the customers, by changing the id of each one of them starting with 1 and then changing the auto-increment of the `customer_entity` table using `ALTER TABLE`customer_entity`AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;` (the value of the autoincrement must be the last id + 1 or it wont work).
I don't recommend this since you can do a lot of damage trying it. The id is used internally so it shouldn't bother you much, unless your OCD sensors are tingling :).

Comment: i already removed all the customers, after that when a customer registered it goes to the last id+1. but i need to reset the id

Comment: just truncate the table `customer_entity` or run the sql `ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`